# Returning a Selenium Webdriver from a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

Trying to deal with the creation of a webdriver timing out (which happens once in a while covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587942/python-selenium-failing-when-some-threads-create-webdriver/37593609#37593609)). I can't use a signal based timeout because my server is running on Windows so I've been trying to find an alternative.

I looked at the timeout from eventlet but I don't think that will cut it. A time.sleep(10000) doesn't trigger the timeout so I don't think the timeout itself would.

What I'm thinking is calling a thread to create and return the browser and then setting a join timeout. So something like:

```
def SpawnPhantomJS(dcap, service_args):

    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs.exe',desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=service_args)
    print "browser made!"
    return browser

proxywrite = '--proxy=',nextproxy
        service_args = [
        proxywrite,
        '--proxy-type=http',
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=true',
        ]

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (nextuseragent)


newDriver = Thread(target=SpawnPhantomJS, args=[dcap, service_args]).start().join(20)
```

So I'm having some issues with the syntax on how to do this properly in theory this should work. If the creation stalls the SpawnPhamtomJS thread will stall not the main one so the timeout join should help it move on.

Is this possible though? Can I create a webdriver in a thread and return it? Any points appreciated.

**Updates:**

Just calling a function returned a webcontrol so that bodes well for what I'm trying to do.

```
newDriver = SpawnPhantomJS(dcap, service_args)
```

So I'm hoping it's just a syntax issue I have running this as a thread with a timeout.

This didn't do it however:

```
spawnthread = Thread(target=SpawnPhantomJS, args=[dcap, service_args])
spawnthread.start()
newDriver = spawnthread.join()
```

Wishful thinking there.

Answer (score 0):

Thread pooling.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
            pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
            async_result = pool.apply_async(SpawnPhantomJS, (dcap, service_args))
            newDriver = async_result.get(10)
```